# the string doesn't display the content but show a int 0 in xcode lldb

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

When I debug in lldb, the string doesn't display the content but show a int 0. Any help?

[image]

Comment: @orkenstein's command should be executed in the console.

Comment: @orkenstein you are right but i want it show on the label. It was before. Execute a cmd is not convenient.

Comment: What's your optimisation level?

Comment: @Macmade what's optimisation level?

Comment: @Andrew In your build settings. Optimization often has an impact on the debugger, so be sure optimization is turned off while debugging